# joining and empty with other object

Tags: modeling

I want to join the camera with the empty using ctrl+j but this command is not working with the empty object.

reason to join is to change the local axis of the camera. I wanted to attach the file but I did not find attachment option here.

if it is not possible then any one can tell me that how to change the local axis of rotation without rotation the object in blender Thanks in advance

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6453" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6453/)

Comment: the embed script for the upload should not be added as a comment, please edit your question to include the above link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "join" a camera with an empty, join (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) is to make 1 object from several, what you probably want to do is parent: Select the child, then the parent, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: thanks but please check out the file. camera has different local axis than empty I want to copy the empty local axix to the camera on the same position of camera .. ctrl +p not working it changes camera position. thanks

Comment: Your camera is animated + it has a constraint called Camera Solver, are you sure it's not your problem?